# Pass 2 values to validator

Tags: python, django, django-forms, passwords, django-validation

In Django I try in forms create validator with compare password and confirm_password and I don't want do it in clean method. I want my do cystom validator and put him to widget confirm_password field.

I don't know ho pass two values password and confirm_password to my Validator.

```
def validate_test():
    cleaned_data = super(UserSignUpForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
    print(f'password:{password}\nconfirm_password: {confirm_password}')

    if password != confirm_password:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(password)s and %(confirm_password)s does not match - test'),
            params={'password': password, 'confirm_password': confirm_password},
        )


class UserSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    password = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(8, message="Zbyt krótkie hasło, min. 8 znaków")],
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'style':'max-width: 20em; margin:auto', 'autocomplete':'off'}))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        label="Confirm password",
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(8, message="Zbyt krótkie hasło, min. 8 znaków"), validate_test()],
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'style':'max-width: 20em; margin:auto', 'autocomplete':'off'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", 'first_name', 'last_name', "password")
        help_texts = {"username": None}
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'max-width: 20em; margin:auto'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'max-width: 20em; margin:auto'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'max-width: 20em; margin:auto'}),

        }
```

No I have different messages in web site [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add [**`clean()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean)) method to your form:

```
class UserSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    ...
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        print(f'password:{password}\nconfirm_password: {confirm_password}')

        if password != confirm_password:
            msg = _('%(password)s and %(confirm_password)s does not match - test') % {
                'password': password, 'confirm_password': confirm_password
            })
            # raise ValidationError(msg)
            # or use add_error()
            self.add_error('password', msg)
            self.add_error('confirm_password', msg)
```

It is also suggested by Django:

> We are performing validation on more than one field at a time, so the
> form’s clean() method is a good spot to do this. Notice that we are
> talking about the clean() method on the form here, whereas earlier we
> were writing a clean() method on a field. It’s important to keep the
> field and form difference clear when working out where to validate
> things. Fields are single data points, forms are a collection of
> fields.

See also [Cleaning a specific field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Comment: I don't want it in clean method in form becouse in front web site I have diffrent validation messages with validations in widgets. I edit post on this looks.

Comment: @darek_82, you can use `self.add_error('password', msg)` and `self.add_error('confirm_password', msg)` to add error to the fields.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank You :)